# Parsing a large txt file with Pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a large .txt file, close to 2gb. first i tried this 
`pd.read_csv("large_text_file.txt", header=0, delim_whitespace=True)`
which keep throwing a `Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 32 fields in line 3,  saw 36` error

then i tried this: `pd.read_csv("wspace.csv", header=0, sep=r"\s+")` but because its not technically a `csv` file and some of the content such as "names" have spaces in them, the output turns out really bad. and using pandas `error_bad_lines=False` is not ideal as it just skips over ALL the rows for this particular table. is there any way to format a large txt file into csv? i know you can change the extension from `.txt` to `.csv` but without the commas int he right place i get a poor output. example data to illustrate my pain below.

instead of showing something like this:

`╔══════════════════════════════════╦═════════╦════════════════════════╗
║               Col1               ║  Col2   ║          Col3          ║
╠══════════════════════════════════╬═════════╬════════════════════════╣
║ Value 1                          ║ Value 2 ║ 123                    ║
║ Separate                         ║ cols    ║ with a tab or 4 spaces ║
║ This is a row with only one cell ║         ║                        ║
╚══════════════════════════════════╩═════════╩════════════════════════╝`

it shows this, which causes the "token error"

`╔════════════════╦════════════════════╦════════════════════════╦═══╦══╦═════╗
║ Col1 Col2 Col3 ║                    ║                        ║   ║  ║     ║
╠════════════════╬════════════════════╬════════════════════════╬═══╬══╬═════╣
║ Value          ║ 1                  ║ Value                  ║ 2 ║  ║ 123 ║
║ Separate       ║ cols               ║ with a tab or 4 spaces ║   ║  ║     ║
║ This is a row  ║ with only one cell ║                        ║   ║  ║     ║
╚════════════════╩════════════════════╩════════════════════════╩═══╩══╩═════╝`

Comment: Can you show what the first 5 lines of your data file actually look like? Edit it into your post and people can see what settings you should be using for your delimiter etc.

Comment: Do not use `read_csv` in this problem, use some sort of scanner or better streams. First, your data apparently does not conform with a tabular format. Second, even more important, do you have any good reason to read all 2Gb into memory and process later instead of processing this as a stream and redirecting the output somewhere? Because as soon as you solve the reading problem you will face a memory problem.

Comment: @Oleg I don't think the included examples are his data, they're his output. The original data might be in an OK tabular format, it's hard to tell at the moment.

Comment: @Marius Yes, it is output and it shows us the content, which reads: "Separate cols with a tab or 4 spaces" -- this is no good for `read_csv` because neither tab nor 4 spaces are probably guaranteed. I would read the file line by line with some scanner (no python since 2 years, so I would need to look up what is available), parse it using a string splitter with regex, do whatever I have to per line and then dump it back into a result file. Unless he is happy to give away 4-6Gb to this, he will run into memory issues when reading it into memory as is. This is not a python or pandas problem.

Comment: @oleg i disagree with "this is not a python or pandas problem" i need to do data analysis on this file specifically and the way it was deliver to me is currently causing problems. so yes later i have open the file but thanks to pandas i can use the `chunksize` command to get the information i need. my current problem is trying to get pandas to parse the file.

Comment: @Joseph The fact that you are using pandas in python does not turn a generic problem of reading somewhat less structured data of a relatively large size into a python or pandas problem. You need to understand the structure of the data before you can read it sensibly in and before you can do analysis, in particular if assuming any tubularity there. Use any other tool to visually inspect the head of the file and understand what you are trying to read. But if what I wrote above about spaces or tabs is true you are likely to not be able to read it in with `read_csv` or `read_fwf` for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [pd.read_fwf](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html).

For example:

```
pd.read_fwf("large_text_file.txt")
```